# Why do all the Lazarus agents drive old cars

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lazarus-project-tv

In the 2022 series The Lazarus Project, all the Lazarus agents are seen driving significantly old cars.  For example, George is seen driving an "F Reg" (1988/1989) Ford Fiesta in 2024.  Other cars on the road are contemporary.

Is there an in-universe explanation for this?

Comment: Since the show is about time travel I'd hazard it's so that the car doesn't look out of place in a previous era?

Comment: @DJClayworth sadly no, one of the rules of time travel in this show is you can't go back more than 1 year, so cars just a few years old would be fine.